# Joomla auto login from foreign script

Tags: javascript, perl, bash, joomla, automation

I am trying to make a script which will login on a Joomla! site and after a simple page refresh will return the value i need.

I thought of something simple like:

```
wget --useragent="" --load-cookies="" --save-cookies="" --keep-session-cookies --post-data="?option=com_user&username=testuser&passwd=testpassword&Submit=Login&option=com_user&task=login&return=token=1" --quiet -O file http://site/index.php
```

But it returns

`"You should enable JavaScript to login or register"`

So i was wondering if such thing is possible? I've tried to use Perl with Mechanize, but the problem is that there is a JavaScript authorization.

Comment: You may have to use a browser automation solution such as Selenium or Watir/Watin. These would certainly work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone still need this, below you can find the whole solution:

```
function login {
    Server=$1
    User=$2
    Pass=$3
    Token=`wget \
        --quiet \
        --load-cookies ~/cookies.${User}.txt \
        --save-cookies ~/cookies.${User}.txt \
        --keep-session-cookies \
        --output-document=- \
        "http://${Server}/site/log-in.html" | grep hidden | grep name | grep value | tail -n 2 | grep -v username | awk {'print $3'} | cut -d= -f 2 | sed "s/\"//g"
#    grep -Po '"[a-zA-z0-9]{32}"' | \
#    grep -o "[^'\"]*"`

    wget \
        --quiet \
        --load-cookies ~/cookies.${User}.txt \
        --save-cookies ~/cookies.${User}.txt \
        --keep-session-cookies \
        --output-document=/dev/null \
        --post-data="username=${User}&passwd=${Pass}&option=com_login&task=login&${Token}=1" \
        "http://${Server}/site/index.php?option=com_login"

    wget \
        --quiet \
        --load-cookies ~/cookies.${User}.txt \
        --save-cookies ~/cookies.${User}.txt \
        --keep-session-cookies \
        --output-document=- \
        "http://${Server}/interface/modules/summary/index.php"
}
```

## Use the function above with needed creds

```
login site.com username password
```

Answer (score 0):

Why this won't work is because Joomla uses a hidden token input to check that a request originates from a page that was generated previously. The token changes every time and is coupled to the session. See here for info: http://api.joomla.org/cms-2.5/classes/JSession.html#method_checkToken

The com_user component will check the token, so if you want to do this using wget you have to first request a login form (e.g. `/index.php?option=com_user&view=login` ), and then scrape it to find the token and submit it with the actual login request.

Note that the token looks like `<input type="hidden" name="<hex-coded-value>" value="1" />`, i.e. the name of the input is the actual token value, just the other way around as you would expect.

Comment: you mean that in next wget request i need to put a token from this request /index.php?option=com_user&view=login ?

Comment: Yes you would post that token together with the username and password in the --post-data part of the second request. So something like ?option=com_user&password=...&<hex-coded-value>=1